# Differing output with printf using %d and %i

Tags: c, printf, scanf, format-specifiers, conversion-specifier

I found questions about %i and %d on here, but all of them seemed to claim that they were the same in printf.
Compiler: Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Note: 15 is 017 in octal and 0xf in hexidecimal.
I was previously under the impression that %d and %i only differed when used during scanf and not printf. Is this implementation defined behavior? Additionally I thought the number would have been converted and stored prior to the call to scanf.

```
Output:
scanf using %i: 017 017 0xf 0xf //user input
%i: 15, %d: 15, %i: 15, %d: 15

scanf using %d: 010 010 0xf 0xf //user input
%i: 10, %d: 10, %i: 0, %d: 15 //They all make sense to me except these last two
```

Code:

```
int a, b, c, d;     
                        
printf("scanf using %%i: ");    
scanf("%i %i %i %i", &a, &b, &c, &d);    
printf("%%i: %i, %%d: %d, %%i: %i, %%d: %d\n\n",a,b,c,d);    
                        
printf("scanf using %%d: ");    
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);    
printf("%%i: %i, %%d: %d, %%i: %i, %%d: %d\n\n",a,b,c,d);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "scanf failed", code compiles cleanly.

Comment: Check what `scanf` [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value). Also read more about the differences between `%i` and `%d` in `scanf` (they do not work the same).

Comment: You are right scanf returns 4 on the first one (as expected), but only 3 (not as expected, by me at least) on the last one. Can you explain why that might be?

Comment: As explained in the (first) answer, `0xf` is interpreted by `%d` as `0`, and the `x` is not valid as part of a decimal integer, so `scanf()` fails to read a fourth value and reports that it read just 3 values.  It does not modify the fourth variable, so it continues to store what was in it before the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);` scans `010 010 0` from the input and assigns: `10` to `a`, `10` to `b` and `0` to `c`.

Then `xf 0xf` is left in the input. Because character `'x'` is invalid for a number `%d` for `&d`, so `scanf` fails the scanning and `d` is left not assigned and `scanf()` returns 3 rather than 4 to let you know it failed to read 4 values.

So `c` has the value of `0`, and `d` has the previous value of `15`.

> Is this implementation defined behavior?

No, it is defined.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me now. Thank you for clarifying, I will mark this as solved then when the 5 minutes is up and they allow me to! Thanks again for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Each pointer argument of `scanf`() must be of a type that is appropriate for the value returned by  the  corresponding  conversion specification.
If  the  number of conversion specifications in format exceeds the number of pointer arguments, the results are undefined.  If the number of pointer arguments exceeds the number of conversion specifications, then the excess pointer arguments are evaluated, but are otherwise ignored.

When the format is '%d', your input should also be a decimal number.

```
scanf using %d: 10 20 33 44 //user input
```